# How to solve an inseparable equation when you cannot get the variable you're solving for onto one side? (Python)

Tags: python

Have an equation where I cannot get the variable I want to solve for onto only one side. I want to solve for that variable for given values of all the other variables in the equation.

For a simple example as clarification, suppose you couldn't get x onto only one side of the following equation even though you can:

sqrt(x)=(a/13)*log(b/x^2)

Since you can't get it onto one side, you can't define x as an expression - how would you solve for x (with given values of a and b) when x is an undefined variable?

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: This is not the equation I want to solve for, as I said. I need to solve the actual equation for x with various given values of the other variables in a python script I am writing. The actual x cannot be isolated in its eqn

Comment: mypetlion is trying to say, how is this a coding problem? All you've presented so far is a math problem

Comment: what solving function, if any, is there in python or numpy or scipy or sympy etc. that would enable me to input the equation as is and tell it to solve for x?

Answer (score 1):

General procedure: Move everything to the left side of the `=` so you get `stuff = 0`.  Replace all other variables with given values.  Make any simplifications possible, like replace `2.37 * 3.3` with `7.821`.  You now have an expression with one unknown variable.  Example: `exp(x) + 2.7*sin(x) -33`.  Make this into a function, with any necessary imports.

```
from math import exp, sin
def f(x):
    return exp(x) + 2.7*sin(x) -33
```

Now look for a value of x that makes f(x) = 0.  Start by finding 2 values that make f both less and greater than 0.

```
>>> f(3)
-12.533439055050689
>>> f(4)
19.554783295812832
```

At this point, you can use a bracketing root finder (scipy must have one) with 3 and 4 as the initial guesses, or continue by hand.  I would try 3.5 next, and then 3.25 or 3.75 depending on the sign of f(3.5).  As an exercise, you could write a function yourself that automates the binary search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradient descent tools to solve it. Look here where they use tensorflow (maybe too much for the example but it is not bad to learn anyway): https://medium.com/@liccowee/tensorflow-to-solve-simple-math-equation-27f42a44f0f1